# IMU UM6 function changed; No moving axes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently built a new computer with Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo. In getting all my sensors up and running in the new environment I'm not getting the UM6 to display the same in RVIZ as it did with the older driver (not seeing moving Axes but only moving vertical arrow... which is fine except it is difficult to see rotation with just the arrow). I've noticed the published topics are different as well, so I'm looking for some documentation/information on differences and any direction on what to expect with the new driver and on getting a moving axes or other (maybe a robot profile?).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195082/imu-um6-function-changed;-no-moving-axes/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2014-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-15**:
Can you be more specific about the differences that you're seeing? Which topics were you seeing before, which topics do you see now, which command or part of a launch file are you using to launch the UM6 node?

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2014-10-16**:
I'll need to get back to my lab to get into the different versions and run rostopic list but I'm away maybe until next week. I'm following the procedure from here (http://wiki.ros.org/um6) and

rosrun um6 um6_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0

to run the driver.

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2014-10-16**:
When I use the rviz_plugin for imu the arrow moves with the movement of the UM6, so it seems the sensor and driver are working fine. There no longer appears to be an imu_pose or imu_pose.py or imu_pose_node.py with the new driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Per the following link, the imu tutorial included in the rviz_plugin_tutorials package (apt-get install ros-hydro-visualization-tutorials) only displays the magenta vector.

FYI - I used apt-get install ros-indigo-visualization-tutorials but same result.

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html#next-steps

---

Originally posted by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) with karma: 160 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0